# Laravel use attach to include an additional field in pivot table

Tags: php, laravel

To start I have a $cart that returns a collection.
Example:

```
Collection {#391 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    "027c91341fd5cf4d2579b49c4b6a90da" => CartItem {#393 ▼
      +rowId: "027c91341fd5cf4d2579b49c4b6a90da"
      +id: "1"
      +qty: 3
      +name: "item 1"
      +price: 9.99
      +options: CartItemOptions {#392 ▶}
      -associatedModel: null
      -taxRate: 21
    }
    "370d08585360f5c568b18d1f2e4ca1df" => CartItem {#394 ▶}
  ]
}
```

I'm using the id to to match the Items

```
$cart = \Cart::content()->pluck('id', 'qty');

$items = Item::whereIn('id', $cart)->get();
```

Then attaching the items to the order

```
$order->items()->attach($items, [
       'qty' => ???
]);
```

How can I also include the qty when attaching? Items attach as expected but also need the qty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: As pointed out [by Twitter user AnellyBot](https://twitter.com/AnellyBot/status/1129458870500364288), you can achieve this by passing a dictionary to the `attach` method:

```
$order->items()->attach(
    Cart::contents()->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
          return [
              $item->id => ['qty' => $item->qty]
          ];
    })->all()
);
```

---

The original answer said that you can't do this with the `attach` method. That's obviously wrong.

I'm leaving the original answer here, since the code is still technically correct.

<s>Eloquent's `attach` method does not allow adding extra attributes that are different for each attached record.</s>

<s>You'll have to either attach each record directly, or manually `insert` the records in the pivot table yourself.</s>

Here's some code to get you started:

```
$order->items()->newPivotStatement()->insert(
    Cart::content()->map(function ($item) use ($order) {
        return [
            'order_id' => $order->id,
            'item_id' => $item->id,
            'qty' => $item->qty,
        ];
    })->all()
);
```

Adapt it to your needs.

Comment: @northify Eloquent's attach() method actually does do what you want. I updated the answer 

Comment: Even better! Thanks for the follow up.